# Add div around all text in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to add the following div and class to an entire Rmd file in knitr:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

I have created the *container* class using css as follows:

```
.container {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 15em auto 5em;
    margin-bottom:-9em;
    margin-top:5em;
    background: #FFF;
}
.container p {
    padding-left: 14%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    text-indent : 1.25cm;
}
body {
   background: #efefef;
}
```

I would normally use a style.css to add this but for the MWE we'll put it in the main document body of the MW Rmd file at the end.  I wrapped the entire document with the `div` of class `container` and get this output [HERE](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/trinker/test_knitr/blob/master/REPORT/doc.html).  Notice the header `# Hello World` isn't processed as a header?  Nothing within the `div` tags are processed as html.  I can fix this by running knitr without the `div` container and then adding it later as seen here: ([The HTML](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/trinker/test_knitr/blob/master/REPORT/doc2.html) and [The Rmd](https://github.com/trinker/test_knitr/blob/master/REPORT/doc.Rmd)).

How can I add the `div` tags to the Rmd file directly?

````
<div class="container">

# Hello World
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(cache=FALSE)
library(knitr); library(knitcitations); 
```

<style>
.container {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 15em auto 5em;
    margin-bottom:-9em;
    margin-top:5em;
    background: #FFF;
}
.container p {
    padding-left: 14%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    text-indent : 1.25cm;
}
body {
   background: #efefef;
}
</style>

</div>
````

Comment: Interestingly, leaving off the closing `</div>` gives what I'm after.

Comment: Most markdown processors ignore content between `<div>` tags, since it confusing to parse a mixture of markdown and HTML.

Comment: They do parse markdown between span tags, so a hack would be to use span tags and add a document hook that converts them to div.

Comment: @Ramnath, this sounds promising but I have read the documentation on hooks and don't quite understand how to make a hook to do this.  Are you suggesting a chunk or output hook?

Comment: @Ramnath I tried your suggestion and if I have it correct it still doesn't seem to work.  It seems the way I set it up it's doing the gsub at the wrong time.

Comment: I realized why it doesn't work. Hooks only work for Rmd -> md. You want to modify the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom template to wrap the Rmd in a `<div class="container"></div>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>#!title#</title>
    </head>
    <div class="container">
        #!html_output#
    </div>
</html>
```

Then call the template when kniting

```
knit2html('document.Rmd', template='template.html', title='Page title')
```

This way you can also add a custom `style.css` to the template